# Pass data from class to Form through different class

Tags: c#, pass-data

Is there a better solution to send data from one class to another through different class? I have image in class ImageProccessing and I would like to send him to class MainForm.

- MainForm.cs (GUI)
- VideoProccessing.cs
- ImageProccessing.cs

I have this pseudocode:

```
    class MainForm : Form
    {
        VideoProccessing _video = new VideoProccessing();
    }

    class VideoProccessing
    {
        ImageProccessing _image = new ImageProccessing();
    }

    class ImageProccessing
    {
        Bitmap _bmp = null;

        public void SomeBadassProcess()
        {
            _bmp = new Bitmap();          //How to send this to MainForm (GUI)
        }
    }
```

My solution:

```
    class MainForm : Form
    {
        VideoProccessing _video = new VideoProccessing();
        _video.SendAgain += (ShowImage);

        private void ShowImage(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            SomePictureBox.Image = bmp;
        }

    }

    class VideoProccessing
    {
        ImageProccessing _image = new ImageProccessing();
        _image.Send += (ReceivedImage)

        public delegate void SendAgainImage(Bitmap bmp);
        public event SendAgainImage SendAgain;

        private void ReceivedImage(Bitmap bmp)
        {
            SendAgain(bmp);
        }
    }

    class ImageProccessing
    {
        Bitmap _bmp = null;

        public delegate void SendImage(Bitmap bmp);
        public event SendImage Send;

        public void SomeBadassProcess()
        {
            _bmp = new Bitmap();          //How to send this to MainForm (GUI)

            Send(_bmp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `VideoProcessing` class has a dependency on the `ImageProcessing` class, however, you only wish to make your `MainForm` aware of `VideoProcessing`, then propagating your message in the manner that you are is probably acceptable.  It does however create a strong coupling between your objects, which, you may or may not care about at this stage.

Another method could be to use some sort of message bus such as an [`EventAggregator`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) or a [`Mediator`](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/mediator).  Both of these behavioural patterns are designed to decouple objects involved in the messaging process and provide a `publish/subscribe` mechanism.

As an example if you were to implement the `EventAggregator` your `MainForm` would be a `subscriber`, listening out for notifications sent from a `publisher` which in your scenario is the `ImageProcessing` class.

A contrived code example might look like the following:

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly EventAggregator eventAggregator;
    private readonly VideoProcessing videoProcessing;

    public MainForm()
    {
        this.eventAggregator = new EventAggregator();
        this.eventAggregator.Subscribe<NewBitmapEvent>(HandleNewBitMap);
        this.videoProcessing = new VideoProcessing(this.eventAggregator);
    }

    private void HandleNewBitmap(Bitmap args)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class VideoProcessing
{
    private readonly EventAggregator eventAggregator;

    private readonly ImageProcessing imageProcessing;

    public VideoProcessing(EventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.imageProcessing = new ImageProcessing(this.eventAggregator);
    }
}


public class ImageProcessing
{
    private readonly EventAggregator eventAggregator;

    public ImageProcessing(EventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        this.eventAggregator.Publish<NewBitmapEvent>(new Bitmap(...));
    }
}
```

When the `ImageProcessing` class `publishes` a `NewBitmapEvent`, only the `MainForm` is notified as only it, and not the `VideoProcessing` class is `subscribed` to the event.  Obviously if other classes were subscribed then they too would be notified when the event is `published`.